# My jump delay code is not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently working on a unity3d game and had a jump bug where the player can spam jump up walls so I have been trying to implement a jump delay to prevent this from happening. However, I cant seem to get the code working properly.

I added a new jump delay function and edited my update function to include the delay.

```
IEnumerator JumpDelay()
    {
        cantJump = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(jumpingDelay);
        cantJump = false;
    }
```

```
if (!cantJump && (controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below) != 0)
        {
            if (!mobileMode)
            {
                motor.inputJump = Input.GetButton("Jump");
            }
            else
            {
                motor.inputJump = mobileJumping;
            }
        }
```

Then since I have an on land function due to having other aspects like swimming I proceed to add this code to the begining of that function

```
if (jumpingDelay > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(JumpDelay());
        }
```

After adding all this there is no delay happening and I can still spam jump up the walls. Any suggestions on what I need to add or fix to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code and description do not show you ever calling your delay coroutine when jumping.
Since you only say you call it “on land” this will never produce your desired result.